# Automating device driver search function

Tags: vbscript, cmd

The basic Windows "Update Driver" wizard allows the ability to point at a folder and perform a recursive search for the proper .INF file.  Would anyone know what allows this to called with VBS or CMD?

I know that rundll32.exe setupapi.dll,InstallHinfSection can be used to automate a driver install but as far as I'm aware this requires pointing to a specific path and file.

I currently have a vbscript that uses WMI to scan for ConfigManagerErrorCode = 28 (Those in device manager that have status of "The drivers for this device are not installed").

So essentially I'd like a way to tie those Code 28 devices to whatever function is being used in the "Update Driver" wizard. A sample code would be great but pointed in the right direction I'd at least have a start.  Much Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't expect something like this to be available in VBScript. After all, when you're going to automate things you're expected to know what you're going to do (in this case: know the location of the driver). However, you could easily implement a recursive search for a .inf file yourself:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Function SearchForInf(fldr)
  fpath = Null

  For Each f In fldr.Files
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "inf" Then
      fpath = f.Path
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  If IsNull(fpath) Then
    For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
      fpath = SearchForInf(sf)
    Next
  End If

  SearchForInf = fpath
End Function

inf = SearchForInf(fso.GetFolder("C:\path\to\your\driver"))
```

Comment: The process that Windows uses in the Driver wizard is already automated (IE, it searches through a folder and subfolders, and installs the correct INF).  No knowledge of the INF name or path is required beyond the starting folder.  I'm very skeptical that VBS can't handle a task that Windows does with the minimalist of interaction in the GUI. (Literally the only thing required is to pick the starting folder).

Comment: Your solution might actually be of some value if I had a way of getting Windows to return which INF it should be looking for.  Windows clearly is getting this info from the device somehow.  Essentially I could search for Code 28 devices, have windows return the correct INF name, use your recursive search and then rundll32.exe setupapi.dll,InstallHinfSection could probably handle the rest.  Any ideas on getting the INF query?

Comment: Nevermind about the INF query.  I just remembered that Windows just scans all found INFs for the hardware ID that should be written inside somewhere.  I guess I could since I can get the HWID from WMI.  Still surprised there isn't an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in updating your driver, that is automatic and manual update. By using the Automatic Update, Windows will look for your Drivers via Internet or on Windows Generic Drivers. But the best option is to do the manual updating of Drivers which requires selecting the path of where the INF is. In this situation, Windows will lessen the time on locating the device's driver and the accuracy of updating your device is 100%, if you have the correct driver for your device.